# Adding attendees with Google Calendar API

Tags: python, api, calendar, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to add attendees to an inserted event using the Python Google Calendar API. Any idea where I'm going wrong? I have tried and read everything I could find on it. Thanks.

```
brew_cal_body = {'attendees':{'email':'*********@gmail.com'},'end':{'date':'2014-08-20'},'start': {'date':'2014-08-18'},'summary':'TESTING THINGS'}

new_event = google_calendar.service.events().insert(calendarId=brew_cal_id, body=brew_cal_body,sendNotifications=True).execute()

new_event

{u'created': u'2014-08-15T19:41:46.000Z',
u'creator': {u'displayName': u'*********',
u'email': u'*************'},
u'end': {u'date': u'2014-08-20'},
u'etag': u'"2816263412782000"',
u'hangoutLink': u'******************',
u'htmlLink': u'********************',
u'iCalUID': u'********************',
u'id': u'v28jdhl0ikm9c2eb859f6rhj3k',
u'kind': u'calendar#event',
u'organizer': {u'displayName': u'Test Schedule',
u'email': u'*******************8',
u'self': True},
u'reminders': {u'useDefault': True},
u'sequence': 0,
u'start': {u'date': u'2014-08-18'},
u'status': u'confirmed',
u'summary': u'TESTING THINGS',
u'updated': u'2014-08-15T19:41:46.391Z'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attendees are supposed to be a list of dictionaries, such that:

```
{'attendees':{'email':'*********@gmail.com'}
```

is supposed to be:

```
{'attendees':[{'email':'*********@gmail.com'}]
```

I had not noticed the brackets in the documentation, and the former did not raise an error. Hope this helps someone from pulling their hair out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
def update_event_employee_email(service, calendarId, eventId, employee_email,displayName):
    # First retrieve the event from the API.
    event = service.events().get(calendarId=calendarId, eventId=eventId).execute()
    #print(event)
    add_attendees = {
        "displayName": str(displayName),
        "email": str(employee_email)
        }
    if event['attendees']:
        attendees = event['attendees']
        attendees.append(add_attendees)
        body = {
            "attendees": attendees
        }
        print(attendees)
    else:
        body = {
              "attendees": [
                {
                    "displayName": str(displayName),
                    "email": str(employee_email)
                }
              ]
            }
    #print(event)
    try:
        event = service.events().patch(calendarId=calendarId, eventId=eventId, body=body).execute()
        print(event['updated'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(json.loads(e.content)['error']['code'])
    return print('Finist update attendees')
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the update functionality of the API to add attendees, here is it's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update).